# Is it possible to slow down the scan time of a processor?

Tags: processors

Old hardware in injection molding machines require that I have an old PC only due to scan time issues. Newer technology is of course much faster than the old stuff they used. I'm looking for a work around so this is actually 2 questions in 1.

Is it possible to slow down the "scan time" of my new PC to defeat needing to scour the internet for old PCs?

The software also needs to run in DOS. I dont know a whole lot about VMs but what are your thoughts on using one with DOS installed to run the software?

If I've posted in the wrong section or the wrong site please forgive me.

Comment: What is "scan time"?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to answer question. I'm assuming the speed at which the processor moves. I'm having to use terminology that's used by the techs that dealt with these issues back in the 90's.

Comment: You should look to figure that out first, otherwise this question isn't really answerable. It would just be guesswork on our part.

Comment: I did shortly after the question was asked. They are referring to the speed at the which the processor works. I did also find someone talking about using a virtual machine to achieve this but they never left a reply stating whether or not it worked.

Comment: "the speed at the which the processor works" is really general, that doesn't really mean anything